# Seeming inconsistency in the way transpose |: works

Tags: j

Consider:

```
   |: 2 3 $ 1 2 3
1 1
2 2
3 3
   |: 1 2 3
1 2 3
```

The first one makes sense to me: the rows are now columns.  But, by analogy, I expected the output of the 2nd one to be:

```
   |: 1 2 3
1 
2 
3
```

Why is it still a row, rather than a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`|:`](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d232.htm)

> reverses the order of the axes of its argument

So

```
$ |: 2 3 $ 1 2 3
3 2
$ |: 1 2 3 $ 1 2 3
3 2 1
```

and naturally

```
$ |: 1 2 3
3
```

which is the list `1 2 3`

The result that you expected has axes `3 1`; you would get this for the transpose of the list `1 3 $ 1 2 3`

```
] l =: 1 3 $ 1 2 3
1 2 3
|: l
1
2
3
   ($ l);($ |: l)
┌───┬───┐
│1 3│3 1│
└───┴───┘
```

Comment: Ah, so was my problem the incorrect assumption that a list of 3 items is the same as a 1 by 3 table of items?

Comment: One way to think of it is that an array has a number of dimensions, and transposing doesn't add any. `1 2 3` is one-dimensional and you were expecting transpose to add a dimension.